# Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, foreign-keys, migration, eloquent

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel however when I migrate my table using `artisan` i am thrown the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
: alter table `priorities` add constraint priorities_user_id_foreign foreign 
key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))
```

My migration code is as so:

priorities migration file

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('priorities', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('priority_name');
        $table->smallInteger('rank');
        $table->text('class');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::drop('priorities');
}
```

users migration file

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::table('users', function($table)
    {
    $table->create();
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('email_code');
    $table->string('time_created');
    $table->string('ip');
    $table->string('confirmed');
    $table->string('user_role');
    $table->string('salt');
    $table->string('last_login');

    $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
        Schemea::drop('users');
}
```

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong, I want to get this right now, as I've got a lot of tables I need to create e.g. Users, Clients, Projects, Tasks, Statuses, Priorities, Types, Teams. Ideally I want to create tables which hold this data with the foreign keys, i..e `clients_project` and `project_tasks` etc.

Hope someone can help me to get started.

Comment: as a notice be sure to use increments() over integer for the id , when u reference users .. I see users table done by Laravel 8 is not increments ...

Comment: see [this answer for the foreign key problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71275576/3612408)

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Add it in two steps, and it's good to make it unsigned too:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('priorities', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('priority_name');
        $table->smallInteger('rank');
        $table->text('class');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
    });

   Schema::table('priorities', function($table) {
       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
   });

}
```

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't think it was that simple. will accept after timer ticks down.

Comment: Thanks, Antonio! For me the problem was not adding unsigned() on the user_id column so that it matched the data type of the id column on the users table. Laravel's increments('id') function creates an unsigned integer, so the foreign key column also needs to be unsigned.

Comment: adding unsigned, aside from separating to `Schema::table` method helped! Thanks!

Comment: For me it was not making the id unsigned as well. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I had this very same error thanks. But you don't really have to separate them unless if you think it makes it looker prettier.

Comment: The solution is in @BradGriffith 's comment. As noted above me there is no need to separate at all. Maybe better to update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Adding 'unsigned' is very important in v5.6, Thanks @Antonio

Comment: there is now an unsignedInteger() so just use: 

`$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');`

Comment: Use `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')` if your user.id is `bigIncrements`

Comment: Great answer, please update to Laravel 7, in order to not lost relevancy

Comment: I have tried all above solutions but still no luck. I use Laravel 7. Any other suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 131):

Question already answered, but hope this might help someone else.

This error occurred for me because I created the migration table with the foreign key in it firstly before the key existed as a primary key in it's original table. Migrations get executed in the order they were created as indicated by the file name generated after running `migrate:make`. E.g. `2014_05_10_165709_create_student_table.php`.

The solution was to rename the file with the foreign key to an earlier time than the file with the primary key as recommended here: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10246

I think I also had to add in `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`

Comment: After you rename the migration file and get some errors like: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory (and the old migration name is displayed) you have to run: composer dump-autoload

Comment: **$table->engine = 'InnoDB';** is required to enforce foreign key at MySql level.  The default laravel engine is MyIsam wich not support foreign keys !

Comment: this worked for me as well, thanks. But it seems a bit strange to me that it works this way. I mean, it makes sense, but there should be a way to specify the order of the migration execution other than manually renaming the files and coming up with fake dates in the process

Comment: I came here not because I was getting any errors, but I was able to add wrong values to the column which was a foreign key. Then I saw the comment and answer about InnoDB. This was good to know. Thanks guys :)

Comment: The order in which you created your migrations still remains important when migrating. I ran into this issue but this resolved it.

Answer (score 90):

## Laravel ^5.8

> [As of Laravel 5.8](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26472), migration stubs use the bigIncrements method on ID
>   columns by default. Previously, ID columns were created using the
>   increments method.
>
> This will not affect any existing code in your project; however, be
>   aware that foreign key columns **must be of the same type**. Therefore, a
>   column created using the increments method **can not reference** a column
>   created using the bigIncrements method.
>
> *Source: [Migrations & bigIncrements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade)*

---

#### Example

Let's imagine you are building a simple role-based application, and you need to references **user_id** in the *PIVOT* table **"role_user"**.

*2019_05_05_112458_create_users_table.php*

```
// ...

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->string('full_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

*2019_05_05_120634_create_role_user_pivot_table.php*

```
// ...

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {

        // this line throw QueryException "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint..."
        // $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();

        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index(); // this is working
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

As you can see, the commented line will throw a query exception, because, as mentioned in the upgrade notes, **foreign key columns must be of the same type**,  therefore you need to either change the foreing key (in this example it's *user_id*) to *bigInteger* in *role_user* table or change *bigIncrements* method to *increments* method in *users* table and use the commented line in the pivot table, it's up to you.

---

I hope i was able to clarify this issue to you.

Comment: Thank you. you saved my life. 

Following your explanation, I changed my foreign key to bigInteger like you suggested.

`Schema::table('goal_objective', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigInteger('job_title_id')->after('target')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('job_title_id')->references('id')->on('job_titles')->onDelete('set null');
}`

It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @BruceTong, i'm glad i was able to help.

Comment: Yup this is the most relevant answer.

Comment: This answer is very helpful.

Comment: Best Answer. Thank you

Comment: This seems to work for Laravel 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

In my case, the issue was that the main table already had records in it and I was forcing the new column to not be NULL. So adding a ->nullable() to the new column did the trick. In the question's example would be something like this:

`$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`

or:

`$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();`

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Note that the 'id' column in your parent table also needs to be unsigned! Using  a line such as $table->increments('id'); will automatically default to unsigned.

Comment: This worked for me. I changed the parent table id's data type from BigIncrements to increments.

Comment: This one is really important also when setting `onUpdate("SET NULL")` or `onDelete("SET NULL")` to foreign ids

Answer (score 29):

In my case the problem was that the auto-generated migration for the `users` table was setting

```php
...
$table->bigIncrements('id');
...
```

So I had to change the column type

```php
$table->bigInteger('id');
```

to make my migration with the foreign key work.

This with laravel `5.8.2`

Comment: Because the foreign key column must have the same type of the column it refers to

Comment: This worked for me $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); in laravel 5.8.*

Comment: I also had this issue with 5.8, this fixed it for me! Thanks!

Comment: Saved me from a long night!

Answer (score 24):

In my case the problem was with migration timing be careful while creating migrations firstly create the child migration than the base migration. Because if you create base migration first which have your foreign key will look for child table and there wont be table which then throw an exception.

**Further more:**

When you create migration it has a timestamp in the beginning of it. lets say you have created a migration **cat** so it will look like `2015_08_19_075954_the_cats_time.php` and it has this code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class TheCatsTime extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cat', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');  
            $table->date('date_of_birth');
            $table->integer('breed_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
        });

        Schema::table('cat', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('breed_id')->references('id')->on('breed');
      });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('cat');
    }
}
```

And after creating the base table you create another migration **breed** which is child table it has its own creation time and date stamp.
The code will look like :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class BreedTime extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('breed', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->increments('id');    
             $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('breed');
    }
}
```

it seems these both table are correct but when you run **php artisan migrate**. It will throw an exception because migration will first create the base table in your database because you have created this migration first and our base table has foreign key constraint in it which will look for child table and the child table doesn't exist which is probably an exception..

**So:**

> Create child table migration first.
>
> Create base table migration after child migration is created.
>
> php artisan migrate.

**done it will work**

Answer (score 20):

In laravel 5.8, the users_table uses `bigIncrements('id')` data type for the primary key. So that when you want to refer a foreign key constraint your `user_id` column needs to be `unsignedBigInteger('user_id')` type.

Comment: thank you very much, I spent an hour trying to figure out why the foreign key is causing the exception

Answer (score 19):

I had this issue with laravel 5.8 and i fixed this code, as shown [here in Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints), to where ever i am adding a foreign key.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

then i ran `$ php artisan migrate:refresh`

Since this syntax is rather verbose, Laravel provides additional, terser methods that use convention to provide a better developer experience. The example above could be written like so:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case I just change the order migrations are executed manually so table users is created first.

In folder database/migrations/ your migration filename have this format:
year_month_day_hhmmss_create_XXXX_table.php

Just rename create user file so creation date of your table priorities table is set later than user date (even one second later is enough)

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same issue using **Laravel 5.8.** After taking a closer look to laravel docs, moreover here [Migrations & bigIncrements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#sqlite). The way I solved it is by adding primary keys **"$table->bigIncrements('id')"** to every single table that is related to the table **"users"** and its associations, in my case the table **"role"**. Lastly, I had **"$table->unsignedBigInteger"** for associating roles to users (Many-to-Many), that is, table **"role_user"**.

```
1. Users table

    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

2. Roles Table
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

3. Table role_user
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

This error occurred for me because  - while the table I was trying to create was InnoDB - the foreign table I was trying to relate it to was a MyISAM table!

Comment: MyISAM does not support foreign key constraints. It likely worked because switching to MyISAM caused it to completely ignore the foreign key which was probably there for a reason. Be careful.

Answer (score 7):

Using Laravel 5.3 had the same problem.

The solution was to use **unsignedInteger** instead of **integer('name')->unsigned()**.

So this is what worked

```
$table->unsignedInt('column_name');
$table->foreign('column_name')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

The reason this worked is the fact that when using **integer('name')->unsigned** the column created in the table had length 11, but when using **unsigedInteger('name')** the column had length 10.

Length 10 is the length for primary keys when using Laravel so the columns length matched.

Comment: Man, thank you for that I was about to give up and run the raw sql as I just found your post. I will have to read about more on why laravel Primary key are forced to be of length 10 and if there is any reason why doing integer('column')->unsigned() should be different from unsigedInteger('column')

Answer (score 6):

We cannot add relations, unless related tables gets created. Laravel run migrations order by date of migration files. So if you want to create a relation with a table that exists in 2nd migration file it fails.

I faced the same problem, so I created one more migration file at last to specify all relations.

```
Schema::table('properties', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('area')->references('id')->on('areas')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('city')->references('id')->on('cities')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('type')->references('id')->on('property_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::table('areas', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: what did you name the file? 9999_99_99_999999_create_foreign_keys.php?

Comment: adding 9999_99_99_99999 to migration filename is bad idea as it will screw up rollback feature.

Answer (score 6):

You should write in this way

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->float('amount', 11, 2);
        $table->enum('transaction type', ['debit', 'credit']);
        $table->bigInteger('customer_id')->unsigned();      
        $table->timestamps();                 
    });

    Schema::table('transactions', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('customer_id')
              ->references('id')->on('customers')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });     
}
```

The foreign key field should be **unsigned**, hope it helps!!

Comment: Not just unsigned but when it references a bigIncrements column, it should be unsigedBigInteger

Answer (score 5):

For making addition of foreign key constraint in laravel, the following worked for me:

1. Create the column to be foreign key as follows:

   ```
   $table->integer('column_name')->unsigned();
   ```
2. Adding the constraint  line immediately after (1) i.e.

   ```
   $table->integer('column_name')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('column_name')->references('pk_of_other_table')->on('other_table');
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Be aware: when Laravel sets up a table using

```
$table->increments('id');
```

which is standard in most migrations, this will set up an unsigned integer field.  Therefore when making a foreign reference from another table to this field, ensure that in the referencing table, you set the field to UnsignedInteger and not (what I'd assumed to be an) UnsignedBigInteger field.

For example: in the migration file 2018_12_12_123456_create_users_table.php:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
```

Then in the migration file 2018_12_12_18000000_create_permissions_table.php, which sets up the foreign reference back to users:

```
Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->UnsignedInteger('user_id'); // UnsignedInteger = "increments" in users table
    $table->boolean('admin');
    $table->boolean('enabled');
    $table->timestamps();

    // set up relationship
    $table->foreign('user_id')->reference('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**20 April, 2021**

In Laravel 8 I have faced this problem. If you don't use `nullable()` then this error could happen.

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
```

Answer (score 3):

i know thats a old question but make sure if you are working with references the proper supporting engine is defined. set innodb engine for both tables and same data type for the reference columns

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

Answer (score 3):

If none of the solutions above work for newbies check if both IDs have the same type: both are `integer` or both are `bigInteger`, ... You can have something like this:

Main Table (users for example)

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Child Table (priorities for example)

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

**This query will failed because `users.id` is a `BIG INTEGER` whereas `priorities.user_id` is an `INTEGER`.**

The right query in this case would be the following:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing i have noticed is that if the tables use different engine than the foreign key constraint does not work.

For example if one table uses:

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

And the other uses

```
$table->engine = 'MyISAM';
```

would generate an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

You can fix this by just adding InnoDB at the end of your table creation like so:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('business_unit_id')->nullable();

        $table->string('name', 100);

        $table->foreign('business_unit_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('business_units')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB'; # <=== see this line
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(Learning english, sorry)
I try in my project with "foreignId" and works. In your code is just delete the column user_id and add the foreignId on the reference:

```
 public function up()
{

    Schema::create('priorities', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('priority_name');
        $table->smallInteger('rank');
        $table->text('class');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
    });
}
```

**IMPORTANTE: Create first the tables without foreign keys on this case the "users" table**

Comment: Thanks, Creating first the table without a foreign key worked. I always forget that :)

Answer (score 2):

Chiming in here a few years after the original question, using laravel 5.1, I had the same error as my migrations were computer generated with all the same date code. I went through all the proposed solutions, then refactored to find the error source.

In following laracasts, and in reading these posts, I believe the correct answer is similar to Vickies answer, with the exception that you don't need to add a separate schema call. You don't need to set the table to Innodb, I am assuming laravel is now doing that.

The migrations simply need to be timed correctly, which means you will modify the date code up (later) in the filename for tables that you need foreign keys on. Alternatively or in addition, Lower the datecode for tables that don't need foreign keys.

The advantage in modifying the datecode is your migration code will be easier to read and maintain.

So far my code is working by adjusting the time code up to push back migrations that need foreign keys.

However I do have hundreds of tables, so at the very end I have one last table for just foreign keys. Just to get things flowing. I am assuming I will pull those into the correct file and modify the datecode as i test them.

So an example: file 2016_01_18_999999_create_product_options_table. This one needs the products table to be created. Look at the file names.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_attribute_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('value', 40)->default('');
        $table->timestamps();
        //$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->foreign('product_attribute_id')->references('id')->on('product_attributes');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');


    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('product_options');
}
```

the products table: this needs to migrate first. 2015_01_18_000000_create_products_table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('style_number', 64)->default('');
        $table->string('title')->default('');
        $table->text('overview')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('products');
}
```

And finally at the very end the file that I am temporarily using to resolve issues, which I will refactor as I write tests for the models which I named 9999_99_99_999999_create_foreign_keys.php. These keys are commented as I pulled them out, but you get the point.

```
    public function up()
    {
//        Schema::table('product_skus', function ($table) {
//            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
//    });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
//        Schema::table('product_skus', function ($table)
//        {
//            $table->dropForeign('product_skus_product_id_foreign');
//        });
```

Answer (score 2):

So simple !!!

if your first create `'priorities'` migration file, Laravel first run `'priorities'` while `'users'` table does not exist.

how it can add relation to a table that does not exist!.

Solution: **pull out** *foreign key codes* from  `'priorities'` table. your migration file should be like this:

[image]

and add to a new migration file, here its name is `create_prioritiesForeignKey_table` and add these codes:

```
public function up()
{        
    Schema::table('priorities', function (Blueprint $table) {          
        $table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users');                        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure your foreing column is over wide rage of foreing key column

I means your foreingkey (in second table) must be same type of your ponter pricipal key (in first table)

your pointer principal key must be add unsigned method, let me show:

on your FIRST migration table:

```
$table->increments('column_name'); //is INTEGER and UNSIGNED
```

on your SECOND migration table:

```
$table->integer('column_forein_name')->unsigned(); //this must be INTEGER and UNSIGNED
$table->foreign('column_forein_name')->references('column_name')->on('first_table_name');
```

---

ANOTHER EXAMPLE TO SEE DIFFERENCE

on your FIRST migration table:

```
$table->mediumIncrements('column_name'); //is MEDIUM-INTEGER and UNSIGNED
```

on your SECOND migration table:

```
$table->mediumInteger('column_forein_name')->unsigned(); //this must be MEDIUM-INTEGER and UNSIGNED
$table->foreign('column_forein_name')->references('column_name')->on('first_table_name');
```

[SEE MYSQL NUMERIC TYPES TABLE RANGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it did not work until I ran the command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

that way you can leave the foreign keys inside the create Schema

```
public function up()
{
    //
     Schema::create('priorities', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('priority_name');
        $table->smallInteger('rank');
        $table->text('class');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
    });
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::drop('priorities');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It also may be your the ordering of creation migration. If you firstly create priorities table, and after users table then it will be wrong. Because of first migration looking for users table. So, you have to change the ordering of migration on

```
app/database/migrations
```

directory

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was an old table was using MyISAM and not InnoDB. This fixed it

```
    $tables = [
        'table_1',
        'table_2'
    ];

    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' ENGINE = InnoDB');
    }
```

Comment: This solution fixed the issue for me on Laravel 6.2.  
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another cause could be the DB engine types. Laravel by default uses MyISAM engine. So if you need to enforce foreign key reference checks, you should use InnoDB as your engine.

This setting is in your `config/database.php` file. Change the engine to `'engine' => 'InnoDB'`

Also if you're trying to do this to an existing table, change the engine by using

`` DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `{$tableName}` ENGINE = 'InnoDB'"); ``

Comment: Laravel does not use MyISAM by default. By default, Laravel uses the default engine configured for the MySQL instance: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v10.2.6/config/database.php#L60

Answer (score 2):

In the automatically created create_users_table migration change `$table->id();` to `$table->increments('id');`. Did the trick for me, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was referencing an **integer** `id` column on a **string** `user_id` column.  I changed:

`$table->string('user_id')`

to:

`$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

The gist is that the foreign method uses `ALTER_TABLE` to make a pre-existing field into a foreign key. So you have to define the table type before you apply the foreign key. However, it doesn't have to be in a separate `Schema::` call. You can do both within create, like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('priorities', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('priority_name');
        $table->smallInteger('rank');
        $table->text('class');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
    });
}
```

Also note that the type of `user_id` is set to unsigned to match the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass boolean parameter in integer column saying that it should be unsigned or not. In laravel 5.4 following code solved my problem.

```
        $table->integer('user_id', false, true);
```

Here second parameter **false** represents that it should not be auto-incrementing and third parameter **true** represents that it should be unsigned. You can keep foreign key constraint in same migration or separate it. It works on both.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the table column that my child table referenced wasn't indexed.

```
Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('dcid')->index()->unque();
    $table->integer('school_number')->index(); // The important thing is that this is indexed
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('abbreviation');
    $table->integer('high_grade');
    $table->integer('low_grade');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->primary('dcid');
});

Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('dcid')->index()->unique()->nullable();
      $table->unsignedInteger('student_number')->nullable();
      $table->integer('schoolid')->nullable();
      $table->foreign('schoolid')->references('school_number')->on('schools')->onDelete('set null');
      // ...
});
```

Ignore the terrible naming, it's from another terribly designed system.

Answer (score 1):

Some times this error may come because of sequence of migrations.

Like Users and Order are two tables

Order table have foriegn key of users 
     (During migration if Order table migrate first then it will cause the problem because there is no users to match foreign key)

Solution: 
   Just Put your Order Update table under the users for update

Example: 
In my case Education and University tables
Education Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('doc_education', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('uni_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In the University

```
    Schema::create('doc_universties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('uni_name');
        $table->string('location')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        //
    });



Schema::table('doc_education', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('uni_id')->references('id')
        ->on('doc_universties')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut solution:

**//Inside Schema::create**

$table->foreign('user_id')->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();

**//Inside Schema::table**

```
$table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

//Working on your code.

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('priorities', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
  
        $table->string('priority_name');
        $table->smallInteger('rank');
        $table->text('class');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
    });

  Schema::table('administrador', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
;
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I think is missing from the answers on here, and please correct me if I am wrong, but the foreign keys need to be indexed on the pivot table. At least in mysql that seems to be the case.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('image_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('image_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('image_post', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('image')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('post')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Laravel 5 when making a pivot table, and the problem in my case was that I didn't have

`->onDelete('cascade');`

Answer (score 0):

I think: the reference key must be "index".
for example:(down)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clicks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('viewer_id');
        $table->integer('link_id')->index()->unsigned();
        $table->string('time');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('clicks', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('link_id')->references('id')->on('links')->onDelete('cascade');
    });


}
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please first check the data type of the column. if first table id type is bigint then while adding foreign key check the type should be bigint in other table.

Answer (score 0):

All the above solution are somehow correct but none of them worked for me.

The thing that was creating problem for me is **Database Table Engine**. Engine type of already added table was `MyISAM` and new `migration` was setting `engine type = 'InnoDB'`

I just set `Engine Type` of already added tables to `InnoDB` and that's it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

Schema::create('priorities', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('priority_name');
        $table->smallInteger('rank');
        $table->text('class');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
});

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

In my case, I did this DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'); to turn off foreign key check and 1 to turn on foreign key check. It's worked! This solution is better for the specified problem.