# Getting error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have this four tables but I'm getting the above error in Laravel eloquent. can anyone tell what am I missing here? But when I remove the foreign method the migration works fine.

```
  Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('middle_name');
        $table->date('birthdate');
        $table->integer('degree_id')->unsigned();
        $table->index(['id','first_name', 'last_name']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('degree_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('degrees');


    });
```

I included unsigned method but still getting the above error.

```
   Schema::create('degrees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('category_id');
        $table->integer('duration');
        $table->string('sub_code');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('sub_code')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('courses');
    });
```

Here's the other two tables.

```
        Schema::create('instructors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('middle_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->date('birthdate');
        $table->index(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And the last table:

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('no_of_units');
        $table->string('room_id');
        $table->date('schedule');         
        $table->integer('instructor_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('instructor_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('instructors');

    });
```

Comment: also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

The order of your migration files matters. If you're creating the `students` table first before the `degrees` table, your foreign key constraint will fail because the `degrees` table hasn't been created yet.

To solve this, you can move all your foreign key constraints into a migration `create_foreign_key_constraints_migration` which should run last.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: @CodeProject having error in freate_foreign_key table still thesame.