# Cannot add foreign key constraint in Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel, pdo, migration, database-migration

I currently have two tables `Symbols` and `Prices`. I am currently creating a migration for `Prices` and adding a FK constraint to `Prices.symbol_id` which references `Symbols.id`. This is the `Prices` migration:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        ...
        ...
        $table->integer('symbol_id');
        $table->foreign('symbol_id')
            ->references('id')->on('Symbols')
            ->onDelete('cascade’);
```

`Symbols.id` is simply a `$table->increments(‘id’);`

However, when I run the migration, this is what happens:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                 
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter   
  table `Prices` add constraint prices_symbol_id_foreign foreign key (`symbol_id`) re  
  ferences `Symbols` (`id`))                  

  [PDOException]                                                          
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new migration

```
php artisan make:migration update_prices_table
```

The schema:

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::table('Prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('symbol_id)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('symbol_id')
        ->references('id')->on('Symbols')
        ->onDelete('cascade’);
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary key is of type **bigIncrements** , make sure you use bigInteger as datatype for the foreign Key