# Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a migration for my tags table like the below:

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->char('tag' , 15);
});
```

Now, I have the following migration for my `admin` table in which i have a foreign key associated with my `tags` table , the migration is the following:

```
Schema::create('admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->char('tag' , 15);
    $table->foreign('tag')->references('tag')->on('tags');
});
```

Now when i run this migration i get the following error:

[image]

Both the tables are `innodb` i have changed this in the settings in laravel. But i still get a cannot add a foreign key constraint error. Why ??

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel) addresses your concern.

Comment: Why aren't you referencing the id column instead of the tag column itself? Anyway, is the database clean? Because that error will happen if by creating the foreign key, the database loses it's integrity, so the fk cannot be created.

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter tried that appraoch .. does't work , had seen that thread !

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter i don't understand what you mean by , is your database clean ? can you emphasis ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik are your tables empty or not? Why do you use `char` instead of `integer` for tag? Isn't it just an id of a tag?

Comment: @Paras No its not a duplicate .. because i cleared all my migrations and now i am running this migration on a new install . This is a genuinly different problem , please remove the duplicate :)

Comment: Ok, got it. Removed

Comment: @Paras thanks buddy :)

Comment: Try to run `composer dump-autoload` in command line and then migrate..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$table->foreign('tag')->references('id')->on('tags');
```

Because in `tags` table, the primary key is `id`.