# laravel 5.4 migration errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

have 4 migrations as shown below.
this is users table.

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and this is artists migration.

```
Schema::create('artists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->text('biography')->nullable();
            $table->integer('week_hits');
            $table->timestamp('week_date');
            $table->timestamp('viewed_now');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

this is songs migration.

```
Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('lyrics')->nullable();
            $table->string('mp3');
            $table->string('youtube_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('week_date');
            $table->integer('week_hits')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('played_now')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('hits');
            $table->integer('album_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums');
            $table->integer('artist_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('artist_id')->references('id')->on('artists');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and this is albums migration.

```
Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('cover');
            $table->integer('artist_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('artist_id')->references('id')->on('artists');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(true);
            $table->timestamp('viewed_now')->nullable();
            $table->integer('week_hits')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('week_date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and this is featuring which connects many to many , artists and songs.

```
Schema::create('featuring', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('artist_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('artist_id')->references('id')->on('artists');
    $table->integer('song_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('song_id')->references('id')->on('songs')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

when i try to migrate these four migrations i get this error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`#sql-f0_11e` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `songs` add const
  raint `songs_album_id_foreign` foreign key (`album_id`) references `albums` (`id`))
```

Comment: If you remove nullable() from  $table->integer('album_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); Does it work? Do you get a difference error?

Comment: even if i remove nullable, it puts out the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel look at this, may help you

Comment: It seems you have problem with order of migrations. Tables with foreign keys should be created after the tables they reference to have been created. Please check the orders in which tables are created.

Comment: the migrations where created as ordered now. in my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created table `songs` at first and then you have created table `albums`. When you try to add foreign key `album_id` at `songs` table, `albums` table hasn't been created so that you can't add foreign key to a table with out creation of that table.

So, What you need to is, Create `albums` table before `songs` table.

Comment: @sohaieb Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to set the foreign key during creation. You would have to create the table then set the foreign key. You can use Schema::create to create the table then use Schema::table to set the foreign key. Example:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});

Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```