# Laravel many to one same table migration

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this code for migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAvatarsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('avatars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 100)->nullable();
            $table->string('filename', 255)->nullable();
            $table->text('detail')->nullable();
            $table->text('pos_x')->nullable();
            $table->text('pos_y')->nullable();

            $table->integer('avatars_id')->nullable();
              $table->foreign('avatars_id')->references('id')->on('avatars')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('avatars');
    }
}
```

When I run the code for generate migrations

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

I got this result:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: alter table
>   `avatars` add con   straint `avatars_avatars_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`avatars_id`) references `` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1103 Incorrect table name ''

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel)

Comment: Add the foreign key after the creation of the table, I normally create a migration for the table creation and one for indexes and keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line

```
$table->integer('avatars_id')->nullable();
```

to

```
$table->integer('avatars_id')->unsigned();
```

Since foreign key id should be unsigned integer

Comment: This change with my code runs perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @SergioBarbosa I'm happy to help you !

Answer (score 1):

For assigning a foreign key in the same table you should use this,
 up to Laravel 5.8

```
Schema::table('avatars', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('avatars_id')->nullable();
});

Schema::table('avatars', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreign('avatars_id')->references('id')->on('avatars');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

field id is using unsigned integer data type

```
$table->unsignedInteger('avatars_id')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set reference on table that not exist yet; try it as following:

```
public function up() {
  Schema::create('avatars', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table - > increments('id');
    $table - > string('name', 100) - > nullable();
    $table - > string('filename', 255) - > nullable();
    $table - > text('detail') - > nullable();
    $table - > text('pos_x') - > nullable();
    $table - > text('pos_y') - > nullable();
    $table - > integer('avatars_id') - > nullable();
    $table - > softDeletes();
    $table - > timestamps();
  })

  Schema::table('avatars', function($table) {
    $table - > foreign('avatars_id') - > references('id') - > on('avatars') - > onUpdate('cascade') - > onDelete('cascade');
  });

}
```

Comment: avatars_id must be unsigned. i think use Schema::table after Schema::create is not efficient because u cant set the foreign key inside Schema::create