# (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

[image]I am new to Laravel. I have created `users` table previously. `employment` table has created in migrations. As the next migration I have alter `users` table to add `job_id` in `employment` table to `users` table. When I run migrations it gives above error.

Note :I need to give `job_id` in `employment` table to `users` table as `job_id`. **soumya** is my database name

When I run migrations without the foreign key constraint, it works perfectly.

Migations : employment table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employment', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('job_id');
        $table->string('job_title');
        $table->string('job_description')->nullable()->default(NULL);
        $table->string('slug')->unique();


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
    public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('employment');
}
```

Migrations altering `users` table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('job_id')->after('deleted');
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('job_id')->on('employment');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('users_job_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('job_id');

    });
}
```

Comment: the error is purely related to mysql, not to php nor laravel, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Foreign+key+constraint+is+incorrectly+formed , once you got the error cause in mysql the edit in php side will be a peace of cake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel)

Comment: Try to change this `$table->integer('job_id')->after('deleted');` to this `$table->unsignedInteger('job_id')->after('deleted');`

Comment: @ Maraboc It give Integrity error.

Comment: Try it like this `$table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();` !!

Comment: @Maraboc same error

Comment: I think the problem is in the order of migrations try to put the users migration for the forieng key under employment migration and in the same file to test it!!

Comment: @Maraboc Still gives the foreign Key error

Comment: Did you try the last comment with `$table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();` ??

Comment: When I run the migrations without foreign key constraint, it works without unsigned()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154967/discussion-between-maraboc-and-shyamali).

Answer (score 0):

change your user migration like this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('job_id');
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('job_id')->on('employment');
    });
}
```

Comment: I have add a screenshot. "soumya" is my database name

Answer (score 0):

In laravel, tables are migrated on first-come-first-serve basis. Make sure that the table to which your foreign key is referencing is migrated before the table that contains the foreign key.

For that, you can change the names of the migration files such that migration for users tables exist before the migration of the employment table in the project directory.