# Problem with add a foreign key to same table in Laravel - Error : "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table "users". Some users are linked to other users via the "consultant_id" field.

When I create my database with `php artisan migrate`, I receive an error `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")`

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('first_name', 255);
            $table->string('last_name', 255);
            $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('consultant_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
            $table->integer('profile_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('consultant_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('set null')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel)

Comment: You are adding a foreign key to the same table. Should be `->references('id')->on('consulants')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user table's `primary key` is a `big integer`, the foreign key field you are trying to use is a normal `integer`.

Try:

```
$table->bigInteger('consultant_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

 Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('consultant_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('set null')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
 });

Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this code in the down method

`Schema::dropForeign(['consultant_id']);`

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

Change following line

```
$table->integer('consultant_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
```

**TO**

```
$table->bigInteger('consultant_id')->unsigned();
```