# Laravel 5.7 migration cannot add foreign keys unless migration is run as migrate::fresh

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, migration, laravel-5.7

I've got a migration I've been banging my head against for a few days throwing a `general error: 1005` and I've checked other highly rated questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel) to make sure I'm not missing something simple, as well as I talked with several people on the offical Laravel discord.

When I try and run the migration I get the following error:

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2019_12_23_200550_create_api_user_property_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `manageadmin`.`api_user_property` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `api_user_property` add constraint `api_user_property_property_id_foreign` foreign key (`property_id`) references `properties` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `manageadmin`.`api_user_property` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
      /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:123

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `manageadmin`.`api_user_property` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
      vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:121

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Normally I'd expect migration order issues, or mismatched datatypes, but the properties table was created back in 2014 and the datatypes match exactly as far as I can see.

`2014_11_06_064216_create_properties_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreatePropertiesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('properties', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('properties');
    }

}
```

`2019_12_23_200550_create_api_user_property_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateApiUserPropertyTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('api_user_property', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('api_user_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('api_user_id')->references('id')->on('api_users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('property_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('property_id')->references('id')->on('properties')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('api_user_property');
    }
}
```

This migration is creating a pivot table between the ApiUser model and the Property model, there was another migration also back in 2014 that created a pivot table between the Property model and the User model that created the same foreign key and worked properly.

`2014_11_06_064259_create_property_user_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreatePropertyUserTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('property_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('property_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('property_id')->references('id')->on('properties')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('property_user');
    }

}
```

I've even manually checked in the db to make sure the `properties.id` and `api_user_property.property_id` datatypes matched.

```
MariaDB [manageadmin]> describe properties;
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name                | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| organization_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| created_at          | timestamp        | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
| updated_at          | timestamp        | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
| site_url            | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| escalation_interval | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 15                  |                |
| timezone            | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | "America/Denver     |                |
| hotel_id            | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| siteid              | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| contact_email       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.005 sec)

MariaDB [manageadmin]> describe api_user_property;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| api_user_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| property_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.005 sec)
```

**What's really puzzling is if I run `php artisan migrate:fresh` the migration works exactly as is and creates the foreign key, but of course I can't drop all the data in my tables.**

So I believe I've addressed the common issues preventing a foreign key from being created.

- Column Datatypes match including unsigned attribute
- Migration Order is correct
- Table to be created is InnoDB
- Tried with and without the `->index()` on `$table->unsignedInteger('property_id')`

I'm stumped.  Can anyone offer any insight as to what I've missed here or how to fix this migration?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you running a migration which assumes the table does not exist while it does?

Comment: @PtrTon not anywhere I can see.  The `->foreign` reference assumes the referenced table _does_ exist. What are you seeing that makes you think that?

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but have you checked on the database that the tables' engine matched? I mean, have you checked that the `properties` table's engine was the same as the `api_user_property` table's engine? I think that the default one was `InnoDB` on MySQL

Comment: Can you also post the lastest (or all if not too many) rows of your `migrations` table?

Comment: @MatteoMeil turns out that's exactly what the issue was existing  `properties` and `propertery_user` tables were both MyISAM whereas all new tables default to InnoDB.  `migrate:fresh` worked because it was dropping all tables and then re-creating them.  I don't remember MySQL ever supporting fkeys with MyISAM, so no clue why it worked in prior migrations.

Comment: I had the same issue too, some times ago. Glad I could help you