# Laravel migration General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Laravel 7.x

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to use two models on my laravel 7.x application : Users and Images :

```
# Users migration : 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

# Images migration : 2020_03_27_121254_create_models_images_table
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned;
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

When trying to migrate i receive following error : General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `images` add constraint `images_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

I have already searched over google without success, someone could helps me please ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You are not setting the `unsigned` properly.

### Solution

Replace:

```php
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned;
```

By:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

### Explanation

Since the `user_id` is not unsigned, the definition does not match the `id` of the `users` table which means you cannot set the foreign key.

### Before Laravel 7.x

You could also do:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

### Laravel 7.x

As of Laravel 7, you can do it like this in your `users` migration:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    // ...
});
```

And in your `images` migration:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
});
```

You can find more information here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

You are missing bracket in `unsiged()`

As per [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations)

> `->unsigned()`    Set `INTEGER` columns as `UNSIGNED` (MySQL)

**Change**

```
 $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned;
```

**to**

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```