# Laravel 6 on Migration: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im trying to migrate on of my table but when im doing the laravel migration heres an error that show.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `subscribers` add constraint `subscribers_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set null)

Here's my table that i want to migrate:

```
Schema::create('subscribers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('account_no');
            $table->enum('type',['individual','company'])->default('individual');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('middlename');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('suffix')->nullable();
            $table->enum('gender',['male','female']);
            $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
            $table->string('contact_no');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_by');
            $table->unsignedInteger('updated_by');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
        });
```

Comment: You can just find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try now

change this

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

```
Schema::create('subscribers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('account_no');
            $table->enum('type',['individual','company'])->default('individual');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('middlename');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('suffix')->nullable();
            $table->enum('gender',['male','female']);
            $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
            $table->string('contact_no');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_by');
            $table->unsignedInteger('updated_by');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
        });
```