# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi i am trying to make category and then subcategory so if a category is deleted subcategory would also be deleted
here what i have done so far
created a model called category
also created a subcategory model

run the migration for the category

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

in my subcategories migration i have defined the

```
public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->string('slug');
           $table->timestamps();

           $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
       });
   }
```

when i try to migrate i am running in to error
which states that
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `subcategories` add constraint `subcategories_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)

my laravel version is 8.40
nd sqlversion is 5.7.24

did change the timestamp of both tables still it didn't work

2021_06_09_000000_create_categories_table.php
2021_06_10_055026_create_subcategories_table.php

even i tried

```
$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: Do you change 
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id'); 

to $table->unsignedInteger('category_id'); ?

Comment: $table->unsignedInteger('category_id'); worked like a charm thank u so much :)

Comment: Hope you can mark this answer as accepted :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$table->foreignId('category_id)
```

Instead of

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to first create the table and then add the foreign key.
Like this

```
    Public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->string('slug');
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   Schema::table('priorities', function($table) {
     $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
   });
   }
```

For more details you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Schema::table('subcategories', function($table) {
      $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

Comment: did tried what u said error remains the same

Comment: Check the reference once