# Laravel migration failing with foreign keys

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

In my Laravel 8.x project I have this table structure:

**plays**

```
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
```

**sceneries**

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

**play_scenery**

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| play_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| scenery_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

In my migration file I want to add foreign keys in this way:

```php
Schema::table('play_scenery', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('play_id')
        ->references('id')->on('plays')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('scenery_id')
        ->references('id')->on('scenerys')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

And it fails with this message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
constraint (SQL: alter table `play_scenery` add constraint `play_scenery_scenery_id_foreign` foreign key (`scenery_id`)
references `scenerys` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint) but not helped any of these answers.

Any idea what do I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. `scenerys` should be `sceneries` to match the table name being referenced.

```
 $table->foreign('scenery_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('sceneries')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```