# Cant do migration laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to laravel. Help please.

Error in the console when trying to migrate:

```
Migrating: 2022_03_15_224441_add_permission_menu_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `permission_menu` add constraint `permission_menu_menu_id_foreign` foreign key (`menu_id`) re
ferences `menus` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at D:\DEV\OpenServer\domains\crm.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

  1   D:\DEV\OpenServer\domains\crm.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")

  2   D:\DEV\OpenServer\domains\crm.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddPermissionMenuTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permission_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->bigInteger('menu_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
//        Schema::table('permission_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
//            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
//            $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');
//        });
    }
}
// the second migration file
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMenusTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->integer('parent');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('sort_order')->default(100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('menus');
    }
}
```

Model File:

```
<?php    
    namespace App\Modules\Admin\Menu\Models;
    
    use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Permission;
    use App\Modules\Admin\Users\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Menu extends Model
    {Й
        use HasFactory;
        const MENU_TYPE_FRONT = 'front';
        const MENU_TYPE_ADMIN = 'admin';
    
        public function perms() {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'permission_menu');
        }
    
        public function scopeFrontMenu($query, $user) {
            return $query->
                where('type', self::MENU_TYPE_FRONT)->
                whereHas('perms', function($q) use($user) {
                    $arr = collect($user->getMergedPermissions())->
                    map(function($item) {
                            return $item['id'];
                        }
                    );
                    $q->whereIn('id', $arr->toArray());
            });
        }
    
        public function scopeAdminMenu($query, $user) {
            return $query->where('type', self::MENU_TYPE_ADMIN);
        }
    
        public function scopeMenuByType($query, $type) {
            return  $query->where('type', $type)->orderBy('parent')->orderBy('sort_order');
        }
    }
```

I do not know what other details to describe to make it clearer what the problem is.
Please ask me if need what else.
I do not know what other details to describe to make it clearer what the problem is.
Please ask me if need what else.
I do not know what other details to describe to make it clearer what the problem is.
Please ask me if need what else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615926/migration-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddPermissionMenuTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permission_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->bigInteger('permission_id')->unsigned();
```

Change integer to bigInteger on permission id

Answer (score 0):

I decided so, for the permission_menus table I changed:

```
Schema::create('permission_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->bigInteger('menu_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

And for the menus table:

```
Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->integer('parent');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('sort_order')->default(100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And everything worked. Thanks!

I also tried to do this for the menus table left:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

And for the permission_menu table:

```
$table->integer('menu_id')->unsigned();
```

and everything worked too. It turns out to be a mismatch of two fields of two connected tables.